# Command-Line Batch scripting, SET of a variable inside FOR loop is not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get the total size of a directory (`_sourceFolder`) (including subdirectories) into one variable (`_localvar`) with the code below.

I tried to enable `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` but it didn't help.

```
@echo off
set _sourceFolder="D:\data"
dir/A-D /S %_sourceFolder%|for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('FIND "bytes"') do set _localvar=%%a
echo %_localvar%
```

However the subcommand `set _localvar=%%a` is not performed, instead I see in the `stdout` some output like:

```
    C:\>set _localvar=1 File(s)         27.686 bytes
    C:\>set _localvar=1 File(s)         27.686 bytes
    C:\>set _localvar=3272 File(s)  1.812.083.061 bytes
    C:\>set _localvar=1 File(s)         27.686 bytes
    C:\>set _localvar=3275 File(s)  1.812.166.119 bytes
    C:\>set _localvar=0 Dir(s)   7.431.806.976 bytes free
```

But `%_localvar%` is still empty/not set. I expect to have `%_localvar%` filled/set as displayed by the output on `stdout`.

Does anybody see the error I made here?

Comment: what is the final output you're looking to get?

Comment: @mael' As aschipfl assumed correctly, my desired result would be the total size (and number) of files (here: " 3275 File(s)  1.812.166.119 bytes") stored in variable %_localvar%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pipe (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) initiates two new `cmd` instances for either side, so any environment changes (like variables) are not transferred to the hosting `cmd` instance.

Move the `dir` command line into the set of `for /F`, like this:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A-D /S "%_sourceFolder%" ^| find "bytes" ^| find /V "free"') do set _localvar=%%a
```

Note that the pipe is escaped here (like `^|`) in order to hide it from the hosting `cmd` instance, so it becomes executed in the `cmd` instance that is created by `for /F`. The variable assignment though is no longer involved in a pipe, therefore the assigned value is finally going to be available.

I added another filter (`find /V "free"`) since I assume you do not want to capture the final "bytes free" line but the one before.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are seeking is the sum of all file sizes, this is a bit more straightforward. It does not depend on parsing the output of the `DIR` command text.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |" ^
        "Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum"') DO (SET "_localvar=%%a")
ECHO %_localvar%
```